# Display Taxonomies in loop with template args

Tags: categories, loop, templates, taxonomy

I want to display the taxonomies within the loop but with customized template.

Here is my code:

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
        $args = array(
            'template' => '%s %l',
            'term_template' => '%2$s',
        ); 

        the_taxonomies($args);
```

The post is in the two categories: "Neues" and "Zweite".
This code shows the post with the taxonomies like this:

"Kategorien **Neues** und **Zweite**"

how can I change the output like this:

"**Neues**, **Zweite**"

without the string "Kategorien" and another seperator "und"?

I tried the $arg = 'sep' => ', '  but this changes nothing.

Thx for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution:

```
echo get_the_category_list( ', ' );
```

Following your way:

Change your `$args` like so:

```
$args = array(
        'template' => '%2$l',
        'term_template' => '%2$s',
);
```

And then, add this to your `functions.php` file (**this will affect all `%l` markers!**);

```
add_filter( 'wp_sprintf_l', function($templates) {  
    // $templates['between_last_two'] = sprintf( __('%s, and %s'), '', '' );
    // $templates['between_only_two'] = sprintf( __('%s and %s'), '', '' );

    $templates['between_last_two'] = sprintf( '%s, %s', '', '' );
    $templates['between_only_two'] = sprintf( '%s, %s', '', '' );

    return $templates;
});
```